# sencha touch 2 button, in toolbar, tap event not firing

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I'm following through this sencha touch [tutorial](http://miamicoder.com/2012/how-to-create-a-sencha-touch-2-app-part-1/), however, I could not get tap event to fire, I've tried with and with out using id to get a reference..but no luck..here is my code..

View:

```
    Ext.define("NotesApp.view.NotesListContainer", {
    extend: "Ext.Container",
    xtype: "NotesListView",
    config: {
    items: [{
        xtype: "toolbar",
        docked: "top",
        title: "My Notes",
        items:[{
            xtype: "spacer",
          }, {
            xtype: "button",
            text: "New",
            ui: "action",
            action: "addNote",
            id: "new-note-btn"
          }]
        }]
      }
    });
```

Controller:

```
    Ext.define("NotesApp.controller.Notes", {
         extend: "Ext.app.Controller",
         config: {
            refs: {
                notesListView: 'NotesListView',
                newNoteBtn: 'notesListView button[action=addNote]'
            },
            control: {
                tap:  "onNewNote"
            }
        },
        onNewNote: function(){
            console.log("New button has been tapped!!");
        },
        launch: function() {
            this.callParent();
            console.log("Launch in Notes.js");
        },
        init: function(){
            this.callParent();
            console.log("Init in Notes.js");
        }
    });
```

I couldn't workout what I'm missing..when I tap on the New button in the toolbar, no event seems to be firing as theres nothing in the console logs. I've tried Safari, Chrome and Firefox..no joy..Could you please take a quick look and see if could find what I'm missing? Is there a way to debug Sencha Touch apps?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
newNoteBtn: 'button[action=addNote]'
```

or:

```
newNoteBtn: '#new-note-btn'
```

instead of:

```
newNoteBtn: 'notesListView button[action=addNote]'
```